# I want to access a ResourcePool selection method programatically

Tags: anylogic, agent-based-modeling

I have a simulation that outputs KPIs to an Excel spreadsheet and I want to output some scenario parameters as well. One of these is the resource selection policy (see below). Is there a way that I can access this method programatically?

In the below, I'd ideally like to be able to return self.RESOURCE_SELECTION_BASED_ON_RATING_VALUE

```
private com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.ResourceSelectionMode _collectOperator_resourceSelectionMode_xjal( final com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Seize<call> self, call agent, com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.ResourcePool pool ) {
    com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.ResourceSelectionMode _value;
    _value = self.RESOURCE_SELECTION_BASED_ON_RATING_VALUE;
    return _value;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is for a `Seize` pool, you can try to use its `resourceSelectionMode(agent, pool)` method as below, specifying the agent and resource pool you need it for...

You'd need to call this when agents seize a unit from a pool, and store this to your dbase before continuing (because this can be different for different agents and pools)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, exactly what I was looking for! Can't actually find a reference to this in the Anylogic documentation

Comment: Is it possible to convert this value to a String?

I want to compare its value in an if statement

Comment: You can compare it to values of the enum `ResourceSelectionMode` directly. If you struggle, open a new question (see some tips here: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow)